# WPF WebBrowser wait with code execution after form submit

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have Class1.cs and MainWindow.xaml and .cs.

Class1.cs looks like this

```
    var login = htmlDoc.getElementById("login") as HTMLFormElement;
                if (login != null)
                {
                    login.submit();
                }


            var registerForm = htmlDoc.getElementById("register") as HTMLFormElement;
            if (registerForm != null)
            {
                registerForm.submit();
            }
```

In my MainWindow.cs i have a webBrowser control that loads page and waits for user. On user input i fill some input boxes and submit form. That's login.submit(). After that's executed my registerForm is always null since webBrowser control has no time to actually change content. How can i delay execution of code after login.submit and wait for page to finish loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the execution of code with `Thread.Sleep()`.
However, in your case, you might want to use the `WebBrowser.LoadCompleted`-Event. This is an event that fires every time a page finishes loading in the webbrowser. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095900/c-sharp-wpf-waiting-for-page-to-load)'s an example of how to use it.